# ARCore Native Error - Android error_policy_util.cc

Tags: android, arcore, xiaomi

Hi I am getting this Error and dont know what to do.
Its an ARCore App which is running on Pixel 2 but not on Xiaomi Pocophone.

Any hint on what/were to search what causes this crash?

> 2019-12-20 14:16:36.085 32175-32175/com.example.android E/native:
> error_policy_util.cc:183
> ################ ARCore Native Error ##################
> BUILD_CHANGELIST:283433030
> BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST:280981321
> ################### Stack Trace Begin ################
> ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc:1260   https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc?g=0&l=1260
> ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc:51    https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/c_api/session_lite_c_api.cc?g=0&l=51
> ################### Stack Trace End #################